# Cannot get the variable data to pass through to popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I have this data:

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE `userid` = '$current_user->ID'"
);?>
<table>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->dname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->dateenglish;?> | <?php echo $retrieved_data->datehebrew;?></td>
            <td><span style="color:#f26522 !important">CLICK CANDLE TO LIGHT</span></td>    
            <td><script type="text/javascript">
                function MiniCandle () {
                    window.open(
                    "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle/",
                    "_blank",
                    "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,left=0,width=260,height=260"
                    );
                }
                </script>
                <a href="" onclick="MiniCandle();">
                    <img height="50" width="50" src="http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Yahrzeit Candle" style="margin:auto !important;">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $i=$i+1;
    }?>
</table>
```

That is dynamically created by the USER.

I have to get the variable  to the popup, and I cannot figure it out. If I add the whole thing, it either doesn't show or it only shows the last data in the dynamically generated table.

How can this be done?

Comment: Try $requested_data .= .... notice the dot before the equal sign. Concatenate like that

Comment: You should define your function only once before or after the loop. And send the value you need as a parameter. What value do you need exactly, the whole `$retrieved_data` object or just part of it?

Comment: $requested_data .= goes... ?? Sorry front end guy stuck doing the heavy listing. Thank you.

Comment: Well, 3 vales from the retrieved_data, but I can't seem to get the one for THAT specific user defined row.

Comment: You should probably first write one function (not in the loop...) that gets the parameters you need and opens de pop-up window you require. Then you can see how you can modify the php to send the correct parameters to that function.

Comment: Yes that is where I am stuck. Again, front end guy trying to learn the back-end. I have NO IDEA how to get the specific row name to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `GET`.

In your case this would look like this:

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE `userid` = '$current_user->ID'" );
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                        function MiniCandle (data) {
                        window.open("http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle?data="+data, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,left=0,width=260,height=260");

                                       }
                        </script>

                 <table>
                    <?php $i=1; foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){  ?>
                     <tr>
                         <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->dname;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->dateenglish;?> | <?php echo $retrieved_data->datehebrew;?></td>
                        <td><span style="color:#f26522 !important">CLICK CANDLE TO LIGHT</span></td>    
                         <td>

                        <a href="" onclick="MiniCandle(<?php echo $retrieved_data->dname;?>);"><img height="50" width="50" src="http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Yahrzeit Candle" style="margin:auto !important;"></a>

              </td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php
                        $i=$i+1;
                     } ?>
                 </table>

                                       }
```

You can then use `$_GET['data']` in your new page to get the variable.

Comment: If the OP will keep on overwriting the javascript function, only the last one will stick so this alone will not do it.

Comment: Dang it did and didn't work :( it added the data, BUT only the last row of the dynamic table. If the user has more than one "candle" it chooses the last in the table. :(

Comment: i edited the code, so now you define the function before the loop, and add give the data to the function as parameter, this might work

Comment: That's amazing! Alas it did not make a new popup :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wish to pass the name as part of the window open request and/or the value of the variable `$i` you could try along these lines perhaps.

---

Updated to reflect the requirement to send name, date of death & Hebrew date of death as per comment.

```
<?php
    $data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `userid` = '{$current_user->ID}';" );
    $i=1;/* to what purpose?? */
    foreach( $data as $rs ){
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>{$rs->dname}</td>
            <td>{$rs->dateenglish} | {$rs->datehebrew}</td>
            <td><span style='color:#f26522 !important'>CLICK CANDLE TO LIGHT</span></td>
            <td><!-- /* Notice the various dataset attributes here */ -->
                <a href='#' data-name='{$rs->dname}' data-dod='{$rs->dateenglish}' data-hdod='{$rs->datehebrew}'>
                    <img with=50 height=50 src='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif' class='img-responsive candle' alt='Yahrzeit Candle' style='margin:auto !important;' />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var handle;
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('td > a > img.candle');

    if( col )for( var n in col )if( col[ n ] && col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
        col[ n ].onclick=function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            /* Require the Parent of the image as it has the dataset attributes */
            var name=this.parentNode.dataset.name;
            var dod=this.parentNode.dataset.dod;
            var hdod=this.parentNode.dataset.hdod;
            /* 
               construct url which includes the parameters for name, dod & hdod
               where dod=date of death, hdod=hebrew date of death
            */
            var url='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle/?name='+name+'&dod='+dod+'&hdod='+hdod;
            var target='_blank';
            var params='toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,left=0,width=260,height=260';
            handle=window.open( url, target, params );
        }.bind( col[ n ] );
    }
</script>
```

Then, in PHP, to access the values sent in the querystring you could try something like:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['name'],$_GET['dod'],$_GET['hdod'] ) ){

        /* Get the values from the $_GET array - using a filter to help remove bad stuff */
        $name = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $dod = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'dod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $hdod = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'hdod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        /* If there is a database lookup involved, use prepared statements! */
        $sql='select * from <table> where name=?, dod=?, hdod=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param('sss',$name,$dod,$hdod);
            /* etc */
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: dumb question - would this replace everything I added above?

Comment: this also dod not create a pop up window. Huh.

Comment: Apologies for delay looking at this again, been a busy day. I had used the incorrect selector to target the links but have corrected them now. In local test it works OK - though I don't have any names or real data to test the urls with.

Comment: No that's awesome! I just need to figure out how to pass it to the page :)

Comment: Oh! Is there a parameter I need to fill in?

Comment: What is the variable you are trying to send? My guess is the name of the deceased - hence I used, or attempted to use, `$rs->dname` as the dataset attribute ( `data-name` )...

Comment: three things. deceased name, deceased date and the Hebrew date of death.

This is what is on the page to retrieve the data:

<?php
echo 'In Memory of' .($_GET['data-name']);
?>

Comment: You could apply the relevant `dataset` attributes ( like with name and num in code above ) and reference as in the js code - append to the url

Comment: dang doesn't open up the window again :(

Comment: In your comment, which I missed, you asked whether to use `$_GET['data-name']` to retrieve the deceased's name in the PHP script. NO - the parameter you use is whatever you set in the url used to open the new window - in this case the parameters I used were `name`,`dod`,`hdod`

Comment: You are so wonderful for taking your time to try and help, and this does pass the values to the URL, but then Wordpress just throws an error and says "Sorry, no posts match your criteria" so I don't think this works. I think it has to do with the e.preventdefault behavior.

Comment: No wait - I removed the table data lookup, and it passed the parameters! SUCCESS!!

I thank you so much.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` in this instance merely prevents the page jumping to the top when a button/image is pressed ( due to the `href='#'` ) - without knowing the db and column names it is unlikely that the db lookup will work straight away - you will need to use the parameters from the GET array to form your sql

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have now

```
<table>
<?php
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name =  "candle_number";
// this will get the data from your table
$data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `userid` = '{$current_user->ID}';" );
$i=1;/* to what purpose?? */
foreach( $data as $rs ){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>{$rs->dname}</td>
        <td>{$rs->dateenglish} | {$rs->datehebrew}</td>
        <td><span style='color:#f26522 !important'>CLICK CANDLE TO LIGHT</span></td>
        <td><a href='#' data-name='{$rs->dname}' data-num='{$i}'><img width=50 height=50 src='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif' class='img-responsive candle' alt='Yahrzeit Candle' style='margin:auto !important;' /></a></td>
    </tr>
    ";
    $i++;
}
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var handle;
/* !!! Mistake was here in this selector !!!*/
var col=document.querySelectorAll('td > a > img.candle');

if( col )for( var n in col )if( col[ n ] && col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
    col[ n ].onclick=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        /* Require the Parent of the image as it has the dataset attributes */
        var name=this.parentNode.dataset.name;
        var i=this.parentNode.dataset.num;
        var url='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle/?name='+name+'&i='+i;
        var target='_blank';
        var params='toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,left=0,width=260,height=260';
        handle=window.open( url, target, params );
    }.bind( col[ n ] );
}
</script>
    </table>
```

which loads the table but the o'clock isn't posting the data and the template file isn't working. It's a WP post threaded through a custom template.

results:
[the table results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIC8v.png)

[the pop up (supposed to be blank with candle and name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8P1Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was my final code:

```
<table>
             <?php
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name =  "candle_number";
// this will get the data from your table
$data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `userid` ='{$current_user->ID}';" );
$i=1;/* to what purpose?? */
foreach( $data as $rs ){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>{$rs->dname}</td>
        <td>{$rs->dateenglish} | {$rs->datehebrew}</td>
        <td><span style='color:#f26522 !important'>CLICK CANDLE TO LIGHT</span></td>
        <td><!-- /* Notice the various dataset attributes here */ -->
            <a href='' data-name='{$rs->dname}' data-dod='{$rs->dateenglish}' data-hdod='{$rs->datehebrew}'>
                <img width=50 height=50 src='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif' class='img-responsive candle' alt='Yahrzeit Candle' style='margin:auto !important;' />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var handle;
var col=document.querySelectorAll('td > a > img.candle');

if( col )for( var n in col )if( col[ n ] && col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
    col[ n ].onclick=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        /* Require the Parent of the image as it has the dataset attributes */
        var name=this.parentNode.dataset.name;
        var dod=this.parentNode.dataset.dod;
        var hdod=this.parentNode.dataset.hdod;
        /* 
           construct url which includes the parameters for name, dod & hdod
           where dod=date of death, hdod=hebrew date of death
        */
        var url='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle-popup.php/?name='+name+'&dod='+dod+'&hdod='+hdod;
        var target='_blank';
        var params='toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,left=0,width=260,height=320';
        handle=window.open( url, target, params );
    }.bind( col[ n ] );
}
</script>

</table>
```

And this is the code I placed in the final page:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( 
$_GET['name'],$_GET['dod'],$_GET['hdod'] ) ){


    $name = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $dod = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'dod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $hdod = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'hdod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
}
?>
<p><strong><?php
echo 'In Memory of' .'&nbsp;' . ($_GET['name']);
?></strong></p>
<p><?php
echo ($_GET['dod']);
?></p>
<p><?php
echo ($_GET['hdod']);
?></p>
```

SO as you can see I placed the final code for the GET yet removed the DB query string. This successfully passed the table date for the CORRECT CANDLE to the popup. I would also recommend to anyone following this to a) place your final PhP outside of your theme for Wordpress and b) make sure the href passes the data to an outside URL.

Thank you all for your help.